# Would setting a char to '\0' leak memory?

Tags: c++, c

```
char myStr[] = "Hello World";
char *p = strchr(myStr, 'W');
*p = '\0';
// Now myStr would be "Hello ";
```

If I do something like this, would this leak memory for "orld" part?

Comment: No, it will not because there is no dynamic memory allocation in this code. But even if `myStr` is dynamically allocated there would be no memory leak. Changing the **contents** of memory never causes a leak of that memory. Memory leak only occurs if there are no more pointers to the memory which would not be true in this case as `myStr` would still reference the memory.

Comment: Leaking memory can only happen when dynamically allocating it.

Comment: Even if the memory were dynamically allocated, modifying it won't cause it to leak. Dynamically-allocated memory leaks if you don't `free()` it; if you do `free()` it, `free` doesn't have to inspect its contents because it already knows how big the memory allocation was. (It won't tell you, but it knows.)

Comment: `MyStr` is still 12 bytes long, even though you only have a 6-byte string in it now.  Your program can still access the other bytes, so no memory is lost.

Comment: It's true that this will not leak but if you ever lose track of the real size of `myStr` then the memory for `myStr` that comes after `"Hello "` will be effectively inaccessible as there will be no way to safely access it. While this does not technically constitute a leak it does cause memory to become unusable until `myStr` is destroyed.

Comment: `Now myStr would be "Hello "` And that is not true either. `myStr` would be `Hello \0orld`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `sizeof(myStr)` is still `12`.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's why I prefaced the whole thing with "if you lose track of the real size". For example if it was passed by pointer or if `myStr` was dynamically allocated.

Comment: @kaylum Since we're being pedantic `myStr` would be `Hello \0orld\0`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that's now 13 characters, but `sizeof(myStr)` remains `12` no matter *what* you write to it. You can't lose track of its size because it can never change. Writing a string terminator does *not* make the rest of the array inaccessible.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't know where you get 13 from. And I don't know what was said that sounded like I claimed `sizeof(myStr)` changes. Edit : Regarding your edit, you seem to insist on ignoring the condition that prefaces my initial comment that it's conditional on *if you don't know the size of the entire array*.

Comment: I got it from the (now corrected) comment of yours.

Comment: @WeatherVane strings are always \0 terminated. technically myStr isn't even a valid C string because it's missing the null terminator

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah you're right.

Comment: @JoelTrauger It's not missing the NUL. It'll in fact have two of them!

Comment: @JoelTrauger it certainly *is* a valid C string. If the array length had been specified with `char myStr[11] = "Hello World";` then it would not.

Comment: @WeatherVane hmm I just tried it in my compiler and you are correct. I miscounted the characters in the string. `sizeof(myStr)` returns 12, which is funny because I included that in my answer below, but somehow my brain decided to quit when I was writing that comment. Is it Friday yet?

Comment: @JoelTrauger that's what I have been saying, and its not *possible* to "lose track of its size" because it will always be 12 from the point at which it was defined.

Comment: I'd go a step further and say that arrays declared like this during the compile are hard-wired into the memory. Their size ***cannot*** change. If you declare an array of size 100 you have exactly 100 allocations to use. That's why malloc and realloc are so powerful for managing memory usage to match the size of the data, especially in constrained environments where memory doesn't grow on trees in the format of 8GB sticks.

Comment: @JoelTrauger  : OT, but  you appear to be advocating the use of `malloc()` _et al_ in constrained systems to save memory.  That is far from conventional wisdom.  For starters allocations most often require 8 byte alignment, and have an overhead associated with heap management that is often at least 8 bytes.  Very inefficient for many small allocations  Moreover it is non-deterministic in both terms of CPU time, and success, so unsuited to hard-real-time and safety-critical systems.  If this were tagged [embedded] you'd get a significant negative response to that comment I'm sure!

Comment: @Clifford for small allocations, yes. However if your data can vary from 100 to 10,000 bytes in size, a catch-all array of 10,000 bytes would be overkill. Malloc, et al, can help shrink the memory usage of a program down if the *specific application* allows it. Not that I would use it every time, that would be silly to expect it to be better than static arrays in all cases.

Comment: @JoelTrauger : Don't tell me; I've 30 years of embedded development.experience, but your point is barely relevant to this question and on its own is poor (or at least dangerously incomplete) advice to anyone to whom it _might_ be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
char myStr[] = "Hello World";
char *p = strchr(myStr, 'W');
*p = '\0';

printf( "Length of myStr = %d\n", strlen( myStr ) ) ;
printf( "Size of myStr = %d\n", sizeof( myStr ) ) ;
```

The output will be:

```
Length of myStr = 0
Size of myStr = 12
```

The size of an array and the length of a string are not the same thing.  A string in C is not a data type, it is merely adjacent characters terminated by NUL.  A string in C is contained in an array or block of contiguous memory that must be at least as long as the string plus 1 (to accommodate the NUL).

There is no memory leak or even "loss" because you can at any time access the entirety of the `myStr` array's 12 bytes.

In any event a memory leak occurs when you fail to return a dynamically allocated memory block to the heap.  Since `myStr` is not dynamically allocated, it cannot "leak".  Even if it were, modifying its content cannot cause a leak - although over/under running the allocation might by *corrupting* the heap.

Answer (score 3):

No, because in C, strings are just pre-defined `char` arrays that are terminated with the `'\0'` character. All the space for the string of characters is pre-allocated at run time and is inflexible unless you reassign the variable to point to a different section of memory, which is outside of the scope of this question.

In your example you initialize a `char` array to "Hello World" which is 12 bytes counting the \0 character at the end. Those 12 bytes are yours to use until the program finishes and will not be lost by conventional means. Resetting the contents of the string is as simple as writing different values to the `char` array. As long as your data does not exceed the limits of the array, you will not run into any issues or memory leaks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

> Would setting a char to '\0' leak memory?

Generally, no.

A resource leak happens when you lose a handle to the resource. For example, when you allocate memory with `malloc`, you get a pointer that must be passed to `free` in order to release the memory. If you lose the pointer value, then you can never free the memory. That is a memory leak.

In the example program, you have an array with automatic storage, which contains the elements ['H','e','l','l','o',' ','\0','o','r','l','d','\0'. It is destroyed and its memory is released *automatically* when it goes out of scope.

Comment: "generally" implies that there are circumstances where it might - there aren't.

Comment: @Clifford A hypothetical circumstance where that character is a handle to some resource. It would be quite unconventional, I grant that.

Comment: @Clifford I don't know about in c, but with the c++ community on SO you have to preface just about everything with "generally" unless you're quoting the standard otherwise someone will come out of nowhere with an legal but unlikely and only tangentially related counter example. For example, someone is using `strlen` of this array to remember the size of some other array and would now fail to fully clean it up and *that* leaks or some other non-sense like that.

Comment: @eerorika : But in the question it is a string.  Granted if it were some other object such as an array of pointers to dynamically allocated blocks, then yes - that would be a leak.  This is not - the question is specific rather then general.  I am perhaps being pedantic.

Comment: @Clifford That is the example. But the question is whether setting a char to '\0' would leak memory. Not all characters are in a string, whether that is the case in the example or not. Remember that people may come to this page through a search engine with their own question that might not match the example exactly, but may match the question itself.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : See my previous comment - the question is specific - specifically in this case - no.  Other cases with other code are irrelevant.  But I take your point pedantry is rife - including mine!!

Comment: @eerorika : a `char` is a `char`, but I see your point - I think it might perhaps cast unnecessary doubt in the mind of the OP, and unless you choose to clarify the  exception cases (and I don't suggest you do), it is perhaps better not to prefix "generally".

Comment: @Clifford I think this is a difference of philosophy between our respective communities. At c++ statements made in answers need to stand up on their own regardless of the details of the question's context. It helps with duplicates and helps future readers that don't have this *exact* problem, but a similar one that might lead them to this question strictly through the question title. This isn't a formal policy but seems to be how users tend to behave. But I can appreciate the benefits of focusing on the question's specific details if that's how the c community prefers to work.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak occurs when you no longer have a reference to an allocated memory that is not automatically freed.

Assigning a value to an array element does not cause memory leak because that doesn't lose you the reference to the array.

In your case, the array has automatic storage duration if it has function scope, so when it runs out of scope, it is de-allocated automatically.

But even if you had a dynamically allocated array, the assignment won't lose you the address of the allocated memory, so no leak.